# Install and uninstall windows service via command prompt "C#"

Tags: c#

i want install and uninstall win service via command prompt "C#"

following code is not working please help me

```
string strInstallUtilPath ="C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\";
string strInstallService = " InstallUtil.exe \"D:\\TestUser\\ServiceForPatch\\TestService\\bin\\Debug\\TestService.exe\"";                           
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(PSI);
System.IO.StreamWriter SW = p.StandardInput;
System.IO.StreamReader SR = p.StandardOutput;
SW.WriteLine(@"cd\");         
SW.WriteLine(@"cd " + strInstallUtilPath);
SW.WriteLine(strInstallService);
p.WaitForExit(); 
SW.Close();
```

Comment: What error you are getting? More details please.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to start a command prompt. 
You have to start InstallUtil and pass the appropriate paramters.

Modified your code snippet, invokes the installutil with the options and writes the output to a string and on to the console window.

```
        string strInstallUtilPath = @"C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\installutil.exe";
        string strInstallService = @"D:\TestUser\ServiceForPatch\TestService\bin\Debug\TestService.exe";

        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo  = 
            new ProcessStartInfo(strInstallUtilPath, String.Format("/i {0}", strInstallService));


        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        String output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET Framework's built-in ServiceInstaller didn't work properly for me, so here's what I did to uninstall a windows service:

```
private void UninstallExistingService()
    {
        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        using (var sw = process.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "net stop", _serviceName);
                sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "sc delete", _serviceName);
            }
        }

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```